# URI Differences Between .NET 2 and 4

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, uri

I am generating a `URI` as follows (this code is simplified and falsified):

```
Uri baseUri = "http://localhost/MyApp/Account/Login";
Uri fullUri = GetFullUri(baseUri, user);
```

GetFullUri looks like this (this is in a .NET 2 assembly):

```
public Uri GetFullUri(Uri baseUri, User user)
{
    string token = GetTokenFromUser(user); //Implementation not important.

    //Create a new URI based on the base URI, adding a query string.
    return new Uri(baseUri, string.Format("?Token={0}", token));
}
```

Calling `GetFullUri` from a .NET 4 assembly, the result is correct, `fullUri` looks like:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/Account/Login?Token=ABC123
```

Then I called the same exact code from a .NET 2 assembly and the result is incorrect, `fullUri` looks like:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/Account/?Token=ABC123
```

Notice how the .NET 2 result is missing the 4th and final segment, "Login"? What's the deal with that?

Comment: I suspect ,in .net 4 , uri has overloaded constructor or there is a change in constructor implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug which was fixed in .NET 4.0. Try using the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx), which works in both:

```
public Uri GetFullUri(Uri baseUri, User user)
{
   string token = GetTokenFromUser(user); //Implementation not important.

   var builder = new UriBuilder(baseUri);
   builder.Query = string.Format("Token={0}", token);
   return builder.Uri;
}
```

Comment: That works. But that code also worked fine (while in the same 2.0 assembly) when being called from .NET 4. Can you explain why that would be?

Comment: Unless you've jumped through a lot of hoops, any 2.0 assembly loaded into a 4.0 `AppDomain` will be running on the 4.0 CLR/BCL.

Comment: This is interesting and something I hadn't thought of before. So there is no way to make an assembly that is guaranteed to work the same regardless of what version of the framework is calling it?

Comment: No. Even if it always runs on the same CLR/BCL, the bug could get fixed in a service pack or in-place upgrade, and the behaviour would change. They do try to avoid making breaking changes, and many changes require you to opt-in, but some still slip through the net.